# How to create a list from a string

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have the following question;

- Given this string:

  (-9.1801505 38.7320159, -9.1800081 38.7316384, -9.1760106 38.7280334, -9.175614100000001 38.7277934, -9.174941499999999 38.7276969, -9.174286 38.7273452, -9.1739754 38.7269114, -9.173853299999999 38.7266373, -9.173908000000001 38.726382, -9.174462200000001 38.725427, -9.174693700000001 38.7252121, -9.1753494 38.7249695, -9.1772258 38.724483, -9.177979300000001 38.7241841, -9.1781305 38.7240326, -9.178122200000001 38.7237591, -9.174915199999999 38.7229978, -9.172651999999999 38.7224599, -9.1716237 38.7223014, -9.170840099999999 38.7223315, -9.1661269 38.7232445, -9.1631047 38.7238009, -9.1621644 38.7239822, -9.1611914 38.7241708, -9.161030500000001 38.7242016, -9.1606402 38.7242798, -9.1605509 38.7242976, -9.1597224 38.7244719, -9.1588452 38.7246248, -9.1574752 38.7248025, -9.1563748 38.7248708, -9.157024399999999 38.7252864, -9.160008299999999 38.7284055, -9.158204400000001 38.7296856, -9.1554751 38.7316224, -9.158455399999999 38.7338999, -9.159123599999999 38.7336254, -9.159243399999999 38.733823, -9.1590688 38.734304, -9.1587736 38.7343032, -9.1585287 38.7344595, -9.1584726 38.7346586, -9.158265099999999 38.7346166, -9.157652300000001 38.7361352, -9.1579041 38.7362527, -9.1576316 38.7366198, -9.1577363 38.7366731, -9.1574563 38.7371094, -9.1564187 38.737462, -9.157724699999999 38.7388573, -9.1598056 38.7379811, -9.1602277 38.73791, -9.165917800000001 38.738966, -9.166425500000001 38.7392131, -9.167036400000001 38.7396749, -9.168542199999999 38.7416702, -9.169788499999999 38.740959, -9.170749499999999 38.7402073, -9.171019899999999 38.7398203, -9.1712919 38.7392233, -9.1716798 38.7391685, -9.1719215 38.7391826, -9.172312700000001 38.7392701, -9.1727472 38.7394396, -9.1738649 38.7388609, -9.174271299999999 38.7365449, -9.174486099999999 38.7343981, -9.1743024 38.734297, -9.174186000000001 38.7341419, -9.1741347 38.7338797, -9.174625199999999 38.7332609, -9.1749603 38.7329354, -9.175330799999999 38.7327162, -9.1756046 38.7326312, -9.176090200000001 38.7325687, -9.1776274 38.7328163, -9.177988300000001 38.7328404, -9.178248099999999 38.7328097, -9.1799505 38.7322568, -9.1801505 38.7320159)

**How can I turn it into a list of lists?**

**For instance** this string:`(-9.1801505 38.7320159, -9.1800081 38.7316384, -9.1760106 38.7280334)` would become this:

```
[[-9.1801505, 38.7320159], [-9.1800081, 38.7316384], [-9.1760106, 38.7280334]]
```

Comment: When you say "given this", what is *this*? It looks like a tuple, but isn't.

Comment: Is the original a string? How could you have `-9.1801505 38.7320159`?

Comment: did you have a tuple of string or what ? like this?: ("-9.1801505 38.7320159", "-9.1800081 38.7316384", "-9.1760106 38.7280334")

Comment: Ah indeed it might be a tuple. I can't confirm because I was only given what you can see and the syntax is wrong.

Comment: How can that be tuple without having a comma?

Comment: I have corrected the question, it is a string.

Comment: are the parentheses part of the string?

Comment: Just an idea: could you use find and replace to first replace all the spaces with a comma, then use find and replace again to replace ",," with ",". Then maybe you can convert string to list.

Comment: I have edited the question. I believe it is clearer now, but any questions I'll try and clarify

Comment: Yes the parentesis are part of the string

Comment: @RichardKYu Oh you are right, I'll try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that this is a string you can do it like this:

```
string = '(-9.1801505 38.7320159, -9.1800081 38.7316384, -9.1760106 38.7280334)'
l = []
for tup in string[1:-1].split(','):
    l.append([float(val) for val in tup.split()])
print(l)
```

Output:

```
[[-9.1801505, 38.7320159], [-9.1800081, 38.7316384], [-9.1760106, 38.7280334]]
```

Comment: Ahh yes, thank you very much, completely forgot about split

Comment: I was unable to do so because I was forced to wait, I have now marked it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try converting the whole data to a string and use the split function :

```
data = "-9.1801505 38.7320159, -9.1800081 38.7316384, -9.1760106 38.7280334, -9.175614100000001 38.7277934, -9.174941499999999 38.7276969, -9.174286 38.7273452, -9.1739754 38.7269114, -9.173853299999999 38.7266373, -9.173908000000001 38.726382, -9.174462200000001 38.725427, -9.174693700000001 38.7252121, -9.1753494 38.7249695, -9.1772258 38.724483, -9.177979300000001 38.7241841, -9.1781305 38.7240326, -9.178122200000001 38.7237591, -9.174915199999999 38.7229978, -9.172651999999999 38.7224599, -9.1716237 38.7223014, -9.170840099999999 38.7223315, -9.1661269 38.7232445, -9.1631047 38.7238009, -9.1621644 38.7239822, -9.1611914 38.7241708, -9.161030500000001 38.7242016, -9.1606402 38.7242798, -9.1605509 38.7242976, -9.1597224 38.7244719, -9.1588452 38.7246248, -9.1574752 38.7248025, -9.1563748 38.7248708, -9.157024399999999 38.7252864, -9.160008299999999 38.7284055, -9.158204400000001 38.7296856, -9.1554751 38.7316224, -9.158455399999999 38.7338999, -9.159123599999999 38.7336254, -9.159243399999999 38.733823, -9.1590688 38.734304, -9.1587736 38.7343032, -9.1585287 38.7344595, -9.1584726 38.7346586, -9.158265099999999 38.7346166, -9.157652300000001 38.7361352, -9.1579041 38.7362527, -9.1576316 38.7366198, -9.1577363 38.7366731, -9.1574563 38.7371094, -9.1564187 38.737462, -9.157724699999999 38.7388573, -9.1598056 38.7379811, -9.1602277 38.73791, -9.165917800000001 38.738966, -9.166425500000001 38.7392131, -9.167036400000001 38.7396749, -9.168542199999999 38.7416702, -9.169788499999999 38.740959, -9.170749499999999 38.7402073, -9.171019899999999 38.7398203, -9.1712919 38.7392233, -9.1716798 38.7391685, -9.1719215 38.7391826, -9.172312700000001 38.7392701, -9.1727472 38.7394396, -9.1738649 38.7388609, -9.174271299999999 38.7365449, -9.174486099999999 38.7343981, -9.1743024 38.734297, -9.174186000000001 38.7341419, -9.1741347 38.7338797, -9.174625199999999 38.7332609, -9.1749603 38.7329354, -9.175330799999999 38.7327162, -9.1756046 38.7326312, -9.176090200000001 38.7325687, -9.1776274 38.7328163, -9.177988300000001 38.7328404, -9.178248099999999 38.7328097, -9.1799505 38.7322568, -9.1801505 38.7320159"

for i in data.split(','):
    print(i.split())
```

I've the just printed the elements, which are of the form :
`['-9.1712919', '38.7392233']`
ps : remove the brackets before converting it to a string.

Answer (score 1):

if your data is a `tuple` of `strings` then this can be useful:

```
data = ("-9.1801505 38.7320159", "-9.1800081 38.7316384", "-9.1760106 38.7280334")

output = [t.split() for t in data]

display(output)

[['-9.1801505', '38.7320159'],
 ['-9.1800081', '38.7316384'],
 ['-9.1760106', '38.7280334']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression to find all the pairs, then convert them into a list of lists of floats:

```py
import re

string = '(-9.1801505 38.7320159, -9.1800081 38.7316384, -9.1760106 38.7280334)'

print([list(map(float, match)) for match in re.findall(r'(-?\d+\.\d+) (-?\d+\.\d+)', string)])
```

Output:

```
[[-9.1801505, 38.7320159], [-9.1800081, 38.7316384], [-9.1760106, 38.7280334]]
```